# Django 2 url patterns

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Trying to get the correct url path mapped back to my view in Django 2. Everytime I try i get a "not found" path.

views.py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()

    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        """
        Get user data and API token
        """

        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=request.data.get('email'))
        user = authenticate(username=user.email, password=request.data.get('password'))
        if user:
            serializer = UserSerializerLogin(user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

main urls.py (snippet)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('apiV1.v1.accounts.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

child urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

Comment: could You post some info about directories structure and about POST request which is send ?

Comment: how exactly do you access this url? show your form / js code. And there is also this "get_object_or_404" helper in your code capable of producing exactly the same error too, you should replace it with try / catch: log error probably.